# How to force file order in concatenation in gulp?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I've this task in gulp:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
csso = require('gulp-csso'),
merge = require('merge-stream');


gulp.task('article_styles', function () {
    var _minnedFiles = ['src/css/bootstrap.min.css'];
    var bootstrap_css = gulp.src(_minnedFiles).pipe(expect({ errorOnFailure: true },_minnedFiles)).pipe(concat('con'));

    var _article_css_files = ['src/css/article.css', 'src/css/article-responsive.css'];
    var article_css_files = gulp.src(_article_css_files).pipe(expect({ errorOnFailure: true },_article_css_files))
        .pipe(csso()).pipe(concat('file.css')); 

    return merge(bootstrap_css, article_css_files)
        .pipe(concat('article.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('second/dist/css'));
});
```

The problem is that the outputted file sometimes has bootstrap first and sometimes at last which messes with the page design.. How can I make bootstrap always be at first in the concatenated file?

Comment: That order should be predictable based on the order in which things are found. Is this with the current version of Gulp?

Comment: Gulp-order is what you are looking for: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-order